# Кэширование json-ответа из Instagram

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

Есть туристический сайт. На странице со страной должны выводиться фотографии из Instagram с определённым хэш-тегом. 
Вывод я настроил, всё выводится. Но страница долго грузится, да и количество запросов ограничено. Само собой лучше закешировать получаемые данные, а затем выводить уже их. Только я не могу разобраться с этим делом. 
И так: у нас есть `tag`, у нас есть `client_id` и есть количество фото: 12.

```
$insta_tag  = 'visitCyprus'; 
$client_id  = 'xxxxx'; //client_id instagram api
$img_count  = 12;
//запрос к api
$imgs = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".$insta_tag."/media/recent/?client_id=".$client_id."&amp;count=".$img_count);
$array = json_decode($imgs);
```

Instagram возвращает objArray, преобразуем его в массив, и получаем оттуда ссылку на изображение:

```
<?php
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }
    if (is_array($d)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    } else {
        return $d;
    }
}
$array_new = objectToArray($array);
//данные из массива
foreach ($array_new['data'] as $img) {
    $img_link   = $img['link'];
    $img_src    = $img['images']['low_resolution']['url']; //thumbnail, low_resolution, standard_resolution
?>
<a href="<? echo $img_link; ?>" target="_blank" class="">
    <img src="<? echo $img_src; ?>" alt="">
</a>
```

Так вот всё это дело работает долго, как закешировать полученный json, а затем получать данные из этого файла?

Comment: Сохранять в файл, проверять наличие такого файла и его дату.

Comment: Зачем усложнение с ф-ей `objectToArray()`, когда в `json_decode()` можно [вторым параметром](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) передать `TRUE`?

Comment: Долго это сколько? instafeed.js, например, довольно шустро отдает данные. А на php можно столкнуться с проблемой, как инста попросту начнет запрашивать каптчу (но может вы это обошли уже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно кэшировать весь HTML с картинками. Проще всего – в файле на сервере. Чуть быстрее – в оперативной памяти, если есть Memcached, Redis, APC или подобное.

Смотрим, есть ли файл, и свеж ли он. Если есть и свеж - отдаём его содержание. Иначе получаем данные из Instagram, разбираем ответ, формируем HTML, записываем его в файл и вставляем в документ.

Отдельно стоит рассмотреть ошибки – вдруг «что-то пошло не так» и ответ от Instagram не содержит ожидаемых данных? Кэшировать ли такой ответ, или каждый раз снова и снова пытаться получить данные от API – решайте сами.

```
$insta_tag  = 'visitCyprus'; // тег, свой для каждой страны
$key = md5($insta_tag);      // ключ для key-value или имя файла

$cache_path = "/tmp";       // папка с кэш-файлами на сервере
$cache_file = sprintf('%s/%s', $cache_path, $key);
$cache_ttl = 900;            // время жизни кэша в секундах
$html = '';                  // HTML код для вставки на страницу

if( file_exists( $cache_file)  &&  (time() - filemtime($cache_file)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $html = file_get_contents( $cache_file);
} else {
    // надо заново получить данные из Instagram
    $client_id  = 'xxxxx'; //client_id instagram api
    $img_count  = 12;
    $url = sprintf(
        "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%s/media/recent/?%s",
        $insta_tag,
        http_build_query(array(
            "client_id" => $client_id,
            "count"     => $img_count,
        ))
    );
    $response = file_get_contents($url);  // запрос к API
    $data = json_decode($response, TRUE); // как ассоц. массив
    if( is_null( $data) || !isset( $data['data'])) { // плохой ответ от Instagram
        $html = "<p>Невозможно получить картинки из Instagram</p>";
    } else {
        $tmpl = <<<EOFHTML
<a href="%s" target="_blank" class="">
    <img src="%s" alt="">
</a>
EOFHTML;
        foreach($data['data'] as $img) {
             $html .= sprintf(
                 $tmpl,
                 $img['link'],
                 $img['images']['low_resolution']['url']
             );
        }
        file_put_contents( $cache_file, $html);
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Хорошо. В данной ситуации у каждой страны свой хеш-тэг, то есть по сути, должно быть несколько кэш-файлов. верно? в итоге получается, в имя файла добавить хеш-тэг и получится как раз-таки несколько файлов. так? и запрос кэш-файла будет соответственно к нужному файлу.

Comment: Да, в таком случае нужно, чтобы параметры, определяющие содержание, определяли бы и адрес в кэше: имя файла или ключ для key-value хранилищ.