# Долгая загрузка сайта из-за скрипта, как исправить?

Tags: php, html, api

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт (у меня таких на сайте 8)

```
     <?php

    $map = function($array, $from, $to){
        $result = [];
        if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)){
            foreach ($array as $element) {
                $key = $element[$from]?:null;
                $value = $element[$to]?:null;
                if($key && $value){
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    };

   $airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json")); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=30&token=**************");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *************"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $products=json_decode($response,true);
    $replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($cities, $airlines){
        $response = $val;
        switch($key){case 'destination':
                $response = $cities[$val];break;
                case 'origin':
                $response = $cities[$val];break;
            case 'airline':
                $response = $airlines[$val];
                break;
        }
        return $response;
    }

    ?>








    <div id="kurorty" class="container-fluid">

     <div class="table-responsive"><h5>Авиабилеты Москва Адлер</h5><table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;"> Пункт отправления</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Пункт назначения </th>
            <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;"> Авиакомпания</th> <th style="text-align: center;">Цена, р.</th> <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Дата вылета</th>
    <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Обратная дата</th>
    <th> </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
    foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
    if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; <?php echo Москва ;?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp; <?= $replace_value('destination',$key) ? $replace_value('destination', $key) : "<b>" .'Обновл.'. "</b>"; ?>&nbsp; </td>

         <td class="mob"><img height="50" alt="" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $replace_value('price', $row['price']); ?>&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
    <td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
    <td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
          <td><a rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" title="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" href="https://bilety.avia-avia.ru/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=<?=$key?>&depart_date=<?=substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)?>&return_date=<?=substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>  </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

В последующих скриптах вот эту строчку уже не использую

```
$airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json")); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}
```

Меняется у скриптов только вот эта строчка, она отвечает за то по каким направлениям брать данные.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=30&token=**************");
```

Мне кажется что-то с этим скриптом не так, но ничего не пойму. Сайт именно из-за него открывается более 3 секунд. Пришло уведомление от Яндекса вчера об этом. 
Заранее спасибо за ответ, с уважением

Comment: кэшировать такие вещи надо и обновлять  кроном а не на прямую curl ом лезть. Я думаю вы лезете curl ом на эту апишку, которая судя по всему еще кудато лезет, вот вам и 3 секунды.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev Артем, а как это кроном? Я просто далекий от этого всего

Comment: cron - планировщик заданий. Вам нужно сделать отдельный скрипт, который например раз в 5 минут будет вызываться кроном и будет загружать этот json и сохранять локально. А публичный пхп уже будет брать json из локальной папки

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev написал в тех поддержку api.travelpayouts.com они посмотрели код и сказали что можно все сделать проще и дали вот эту ссылку, сказали здесь есть ответ на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490089/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-json-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-instagram

Comment: Вы можете помочь подправить скрипт? С уважением.

Comment: в примере по ссылке вся таже логика, только выкинули cron. И что будет если яндекс зайдёт, а файл "не свеж"? Скрипт то крайне прост, вы берете json и сохраняете его, там пара строчек. И в вашем коде только урл поменять надо будет.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Вы можете помочь, у меня уже голова кругом. Сверстать могу, html и css знаю, но вот php это вынос мозга.

Comment: подробнее нет возможности, но смысл что вам надо сохранять $products в файл и читать из этого файла.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Спасибо Вам добрый человек за наводку, буду думать, но для меня это лес гремучий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$cache_ttl = 900; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_airlines = "tmp/airlines.data";
$cache_file_products = "tmp/products.data";
$cache_file_cities   =   "tmp/cities.data";

$map = function ($array, $from, $to)
{
    $result = [];
    if (!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from] ? : null;
            $value = $element[$to] ? : null;
            if ($key && $value) {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};

if (file_exists($cache_file_airlines) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_airlines)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents($cache_file_airlines);
} else {
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json');
    file_put_contents($cache_file_airlines, $get_airlines);
}
$airlines = $map(json_decode($get_airlines, true), 'iata', 'name');


if (file_exists($cache_file_cities) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_cities)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $get_cities = file_get_contents($cache_file_cities);
} else {
    $get_cities = file_get_contents("http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json");
    file_put_contents($cache_file_cities, $get_cities);
}

$cit = json_decode($get_cities);
$cities = array();
foreach ($cit as $val) {
    if (property_exists($val->name_translations, "ru"))
        $cities[$val->code] = $val->name_translations->ru;
}



if (file_exists($cache_file_products) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_products)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $response = file_get_contents($cache_file_products);
} else {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=30&token=**************");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *************"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($cache_file_products, $response);
}

$products = json_decode($response, true);
$replace_value = function ($key, $val)use ($cities, $airlines)
{
    $response = $val;
    switch ($key) {
        case 'destination':
            $response = $cities[$val];
            break;
        case 'origin':
            $response = $cities[$val];
            break;
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66061/discussion-on-answer-by-solo-777--------).